# Resultados erroneos en java de NetBeans a pesar de que en el codigo no hay errores

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un problema con los resultados que me da NetBeans al correr el codigo.
El codigo lo que muestra es un menú iterativo con varias opciones que se repite hasta que el usuario lo desee poniendo cualquier otro numero que no esté entre el 1 y el 6 y dependiendo a la que elijas va a calcular funciones trigonometricas usando la serie de Taylor. A continuación el codigo:

```
    int op = 0, t;
    double p1, fac, s, div, x, p2;
    while (op <= 6) {
        System.out.println("Escoja una función trigonometrica para calcular:");
        System.out.println("""
                           1. Sen(x)
                           2. Cos(x)
                           3. Tan(x)
                           4. Cot(x)
                           5. Sec(x)
                           6. Csc(x)""");
        op = read.nextInt();
        while (op < 1 || op > 6) {
            System.out.println("Opción inválida. Digite la opción otra vez");
            op = read.nextInt();
        }
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Calcular sen(x) con una serie de Taylor");
                System.out.println("""
                                   Escriba el número de veces que quiere que se repita la sumatoria:
                                   (recuerde que si el número digitado se acerca mas a infinito, mas cerca estará la aproximación:""");
                t = read.nextInt();
                while (t <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("El número debe ser un entero positivo. Digitelo nuevamente:");
                    t = read.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de x:");
                x = read.nextDouble();
                s = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < t; n++) {
                    p1 = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        p1 = p1 * -1;
                    }
                    double ter = 2 * n + 1;
                    fac = 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= ter; i++) {
                        fac = fac * i;
                    }
                    div = p1 / fac;
                    p2 = 1;
                    for (int u = 1; u <= ter; u++) {
                        p2 = p2 * x;
                    }
                    s = s + div * p2;
                }
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + s);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Calcular cos(x) con una serie de Taylor");
                System.out.println("""
                                   Escriba el número de veces que quiere que se repita la sumatoria:
                                   (recuerde que si el número digitado se acerca mas a infinito, mas cerca estará la aproximación:""");
                t = read.nextInt();
                while (t <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("El número debe ser un entero positivo. Digitelo nuevamente:");
                    t = read.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de x:");
                x = read.nextDouble();
                s = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < t; n++) {
                    p1 = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        p1 = p1 * -1;
                    }
                    double ter = 2 * n;
                    fac = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= ter; i++) {
                        fac = fac * i;
                    }
                    div = p1 / fac;
                    p2 = 1;
                    for (int u = 1; u <= ter; u++) {
                        p2 = p2 * x;
                    }
                    s = s + div * p2;
                }
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + s);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Calcular tan(x) con una serie de Taylor");
                System.out.println("""
                                   Escriba el número de veces que quiere que se repita la sumatoria:
                                   (recuerde que si el número digitado se acerca mas a infinito, mas cerca estará la aproximación:""");
                t = read.nextInt();
                while (t <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("El número debe ser un entero positivo. Digitelo nuevamente:");
                    t = read.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de x:");
                x = read.nextDouble();
                s = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < t; n++) {
                    p1 = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        p1 = p1 * -1;
                    }
                    double ter = 2 * n + 1;
                    fac = 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= ter; i++) {
                        fac = fac * i;
                    }
                    div = p1 / fac;
                    p2 = 1;
                    for (int u = 1; u <= ter; u++) {
                        p2 = p2 * x;
                    }
                    s = s + div * p2;
                }
                double s1 = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < t; n++) {
                    double p1_1 = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        p1_1 = p1_1 * -1;
                    }
                    double ter = 2 * n;
                    double fac1 = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= ter; i++) {
                        fac1 = fac1 * i;
                    }
                    div = p1_1 / fac1;
                    double p2_1 = 1;
                    for (int u = 1; u <= ter; u++) {
                        p2_1 = p2_1 * x;
                    }
                    s1 = s1 + div * p2_1;
                }
                double tan = s / s1;
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + tan);
```

No pongo las demas opciones porque son lo mismo que las anteriores.
Los resultados que me da al correrlo son, en la mayoria, NaN y otros me da un resultado erroneo.
Le dije a una inteligencia artificial que hiciera una prueba de escritorio de una parte de el codigo para ver si estaba mal y al finalizar la prueba de escritorio me da el resultado correcto.
A que se debe esta equivocación?

Comment: tal vez el error sea confiarle a "la IA" que te haga la prueba de escritorio

Comment: Hola Martín, bienvenido, creo que tu error es que no transformas los ángulos a **radianes**, que es lo que java usa, lo puedes hacerlo así: **x = Math.toRadians( read.nextDouble() );